# ssl httpserver throwing 'Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000' error

Tags: delphi, https, indy, delphi-xe3

This code is throwing a 'Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000' error in runtime. I'm trying to get the server to accept ssl requests but am having real trouble.

I also have ssleay32.dll & libeay32.dll saved in the debug folder. Any help appreciated:

```
ServerIOHandler := TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create;

ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

server:=TIdHTTPServer.Create;
server.IOHandler := ServerIOHandler;       
server.DefaultPort:=port;              
server.Bindings.DefaultPort:=port;

server.OnQuerySSLPort(8092, newBool);     //this is the line that throws the error

server.AutoStartSession:=true;
server.OnCommandGet:=idhttpserver1commandget;
server.SessionTimeOut:=360;
server.Active:=True;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get this error is that `OnQuerySSLPort` is an *event*, which you haven't assigned a handler for.

The point of the `OnQuerySSLPort` is that *you* should write a method and then *assign* it to this property of the `TIdHTTPServer` object. *Then* this method (that *you* have written) will be executed everytime the event is fired:

```
procedure TForm5.MyHandler(APort: TIdPort; var VUseSSL: Boolean);
begin
  // Do something
end;

procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  server := TIdHTTPServer.Create;
  server.OnQuerySSLPort := MyHandler;
  ...
end;
```

You might be more familiary with other events like `TForm.OnCreate`, `TTimer.OnExecute`, etc. These work the same way: *you* write a piece of code that the object then executes when the right time comes.

Comment: Thanks. Is that event necessary for the server to connect using ssl?

Comment: @user1365875: I have very little experience with Indy. The Indy documentation should be enough to answer your questions, but you can also hope that someone else will see your Q here (or you can ask a new Q specifically about that question).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Indy documentation is not up-to-date.

Comment: @user1365875: you must assign a handler to the `OnQuerySSLPort` event if your server is listening on multiple ports and some ports are encrypted and others are not (ie, one port for HTTP and another port for HTTPS). The event allows the server to ask you whether a client connected to a given port should be encrypted or not.  If all of your connections are to be encrypted unconditionally, then you can either have your handler always return `VUseSSL:=True`, or you can use the `OnConnect` event to activate SSL manually instead of letting the server do it for you.